# how do I view an old applet?

Tags: java, applet

I have the code for an old Java applet and the class files. I would rather not recompile it, but if needs be, that's okay too. What's the easiest way to view this applet, when I can't find the right old JDK for mac? The applet is from early 2000s, and I am wondering if there is a simulator or some way simple to run it (it has graphics).

Comment: the Java 8 JDK still has the [appletviewer tool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/appletviewer.html#BGBEAIGG) - actually available up to Java 10, removed in 11

Comment: If it's possible for you to post the code we might be able to advise you how to turn it into something that is runnable within an application rather than in the context of a normal applet. This will make it easier for you to use it

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [CheerpJ Applet Runner](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cheerpj-applet-runner/bbmolahhldcbngedljfadjlognfaaein) Chrome extension. It's free for personal use.

Full disclosure: I am CTO of Leaning Technologies, the company behind this tool. Join our [Discord](https://discord.gg/X9ruPkchM5) for support.

Comment: thank you! I tried the plug-in, but it seems to be unstable in the sense that it kind of works, but not quite (it breaks in the middle, for example), and also the applet is a game -- and on a more modern computer, it is way too fast. are there solutions to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Japplis Applet Runner](https://www.japplis.com/applet-runner/) IDE plugin (JetBrains, Eclipse, NetBeans) to run it in your IDE. It's a free plug-in.

Disclosure: I'm the author of the plug-ins.